# jQuery $(window).on() does not work for popup window in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, onload

I am trying to send data to a popup window which opens by clicking a button.
All my code is in php where I include javascript and html, I will just show html and js here.
Consider my popup window (say, popupwindow.html) code as just

```
<div id = 'getData'></div>
```

Now on the page(say, main.js) where I put the button clicking which the popup opens, I am computing some data and trying to send it to *popupwindow.html*.
Here is relevant *main.js* code that gets executed after clicking the button

```
    var popup = window.open("popupwindow.html", "popup", extraParams); //ignore extraParams

    $(popup).on('load', function() {
        //console.log("inside onload function");
        popup.document.getElementById("getData").innerHTML = data; //here data is some string
    });
```

Now this code works perfectly on Chrome and Firefox, but in IE load() function does not get executed. I know this because the *console.log* line when uncommented, does not print on the console. Tried versions of jQuery from 1.2.3 to 2.2.1 where the code runs successfully on Chrome and Firefox(but not in IE)

Note: I cannot execute the required code on popup page(popupwindow.html) because of some constraints. I have to write it on main.js and send it to popup.

I saw all other questions which said onload() or similar function in IE gives problems but I still could not find the appropriate solution. Please let me know how I can fix this for IE.

Comment: So `var popup = window.open(...);
popup.addEventListener('load', yourrFunction, false);` does not work also?

Comment: @epascarello Yeah. Tried that too. Does not work. :(